# How can I send the variable?

Tags: php, laravel-8

my controller:

```
 function index(){

        $properties = DB::table('properties')->get();
        $data = $properties->toArray();
        $name="Toni";

        // return view('lemon_properties')->with('properties', $properties);
        //    return view('lemon_properties')->with(['properties', $properties]);

        // return view('lemon_properties')->compact('properties');
        return view('lemon_properties', compact('name'));

        // return view('lemon_properties', ['properties' => $properties])->render();

        // return view('lemon_properties')->response()->json($properties);
    }
```

my view.bade:

```
@foreach ($data as $property)
     <td>{{$property}}</td>
@endforeach 
               
<div>{{$name}}</div>
```

Comment: Welcome. That's how you send it. What doesn't work? There's [Passing Data To Views](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: I'm trying to send $data, $properties or $name from the controller to my view.blade. But I can't. Somebody knows why??

Comment: You're only sending `$name` in your code. Did you read the link I posted, it's explained there

Comment: That's right, but the $name is undefined in my view blade too... and I don't know why!?? Because I defined it in the controller...

Comment: Is that `lemon_properties.blade.php` you're showing? What's the route you use?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have tried post, get and resources.  
Route::post("/admin",[selectController::class, "index"]);
// Route::get("/admin",[selectController::class, "index"]);
// Route::resource("/admin", selectController::class);
Which one should been used?

Answer (score 0):

To send multiple values to your view, you should add the variables you wish to send to compact:

```
return view('lemon_properties', compact('name', 'data');
```

You can now use $data and $name in your view.

Ideally you should use  the $properties-variable as it is a collection. This is similar to an array, but have some nice Quality-of-life functions added.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections

Comment: I do it but doesn't works.... Maybe I need to import or install something?

Comment: Or it's mandatory to make a model for it?